# warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect gcc 4.4.7

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I need your help for the following warning in Linux gcc 4.4.7

```
for (int iLoop1= 0; iLoop1< iLoopN; ++iLoop1, ++iLoop2, !iIsOk)
```

I have the following warnings coming from the last argument after the last comma

```
error: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

I have read the wiki page on comma operator but I do not understand the problem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

EDIT :
effectively !iIsOk does nothing
I have tested the following code

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int iIsOk = 0;

    for (int iLoop1 = 0; iLoop1 < 2; iLoop1++, !iIsOk)
    {
       std::cout << "IsOk=" << iIsOk << std::endl;
    }

      for (int iLoop1 = 0; iLoop1 < 2; iLoop1++, iIsOk = !iIsOk)
    {
       std::cout << "IsOk2=" << iIsOk << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
IsOk=0
IsOk=0
IsOk2=0
IsOk2=1
```

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with the expression `!iIsOk`?

Comment: Shouldn't that last variable be `iAmOk`?

Comment: i means int , I use a prefix depending of the type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!iIsOk` although evaluated, does not do anything; i.e. removing it will have absolutely no effect on the program.

Your helpful compiler is warning you of this.

Did you mean to write `!iIsOk` as part of the *stopping condition* in the loop:

`iLoop1< iLoopN && iIsOk`

or *toggle* it using

`iLoop1++, iIsOk = !iIsOk`

or the flashier (which personally I find clearer since there are fewer variable repeats)

`iLoop1++, iIsOk ^= true`

Answer (score 3):

First, let me tell you the reason behind the warning message. As per the comma operator properties, from `C11`, chapter §6.5.17 (*emphasis mine*)

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. **Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.**

So, here, in your case, the *final* RHS operand is `.... , !iIsOk`, for which , the produced value is unused. Hence the warning. You need to either make use of the value, or you can get rid of the statement, as in it's current state, it has no effect on the program whatsoever.

That said, as mentioned in the other answer(s) by  [tilz0R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625146/2173917) and [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44625188/2173917), per your "specific" requirement, the statement should be `iIsOk = !iIsOk` but I'd recommend putting this as the last statement in the loop body, for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

`!iIsOk` should be `iIsOk = !iIsOk`.

If C has operator like `i++` or `++i`, thing you did with `!iIsOk` does nothing. If you want result, you have to assing it somewhere.

To *negate* variable, use `iIsOk = !iIsOk;` and you will have desired effect.

Comment: Wow...how did you come to this conclusion? you mind a little elaboration?

Comment: Because `++iLoop` is the same as `iLoop = iLoop + 1` in your case because C knows this operator. On the other hand, C does not know about `!iLoop` and result must be assigned somewhere.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I've updated an answer. If you don't mind.

Comment: No, an assignment is __not__ a mandate, a comparison either will do just fine.

Comment: And what you compare in this part of `for` loop? @SouravGhosh

Comment: @tilz0R Nothing, I'm not a magician or mind-reader. :) But the logic stands.

Comment: @SouravGhosh so my answer is completelly correct but I've been downvoted, why? I guess from you, of course.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. As I already mentioned, assignment is __not the only__ option, so it's misleading, if you make some effort to update the answer, I have no problem in removing the DV. but in it's current from, yes, I'm one of the DVers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh and what is the other option to negate variable? This is really interesting for me at that time.

Comment: My downvote: This most certainly doesn't solve OPs problem.

Comment: @tilz0R I guess you're missing the point, it's __not about negating variable__, it's about the warning in OP's question. __any__, I repeat, Any  usage of the computed result will do just fine.

Comment: @tilz0R: yes perfectly

Comment: @FelixPalmen look, it solved the OPs problem. Oops, what now?

Comment: @tilz0R lucky guess. still you shouldn't answer with just a guess.